# Making a button save to a variable

Tags: swift

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var Name: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var Phonenumb: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var phoneLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Phone: NSLayoutConstraint!

    @IBOutlet weak var Date: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var County: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var killCountLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var killDate: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var killDateLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var points: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var pointsLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var Email: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var Address: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var addressLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var page2Button: UIButton!

    @IBAction func saveTextToVar(sender: UIButton) { 
        var nameText: Name.text // problem is here (Error: Use of undeclared type 'Name')
    }
```

My app is a simple form app that will send me people's forms when they fill them out. What I would like it to do is when I push the button (`page2Button`) is for it to send me to the second `tableViewController` and save all of my textFields to a variable then send them to my Firebase. (I have not installed Firebase yet).

My question is why is there an undeclared type Error when I already have a var named `Name`? And how do I fix it?

Comment: You're not declaring the type of of the var nameText. Instead you want to use = to assign Name.text to the var nameText. : operator is usually used to signify the type of the variable explicitly though swift infers it automatically 99% of the times. I suggest you go through the basics and then head over to app development. Here just do var nameText = Name.text.

Comment: Omg I'm stupid I knew that (kinda). Thanks!

Comment: Will this execute with page2Button on press? Because I will later have other buttons for other pages.